# Android GRPC Protobuf not building/linking correctly

Tags: java, android, grpc, proto, protobuf-java

I am using protobufs in gradle java in my project but am having an issue parsing the proto below
https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/lnrpc/rpc.proto

It seems to not build correctly and all of my classes are not found

If I comment out "with //" the lines below it builds, but not sure why?

```
message MultiChanBackup {
    /**
    Is the set of all channels that are included in this multi-channel backup.
    */
    //repeated ChannelPoint chan_points = 1 [ json_name = "chan_points" ];

    /**
    A single encrypted blob containing all the static channel backups of the
    channel listed above. This can be stored as a single file or blob, and
    safely be replaced with any prior/future versions.
    */
    //bytes multi_chan_backup = 2 [ json_name = "multi_chan_backup" ];
}

message ChanBackupExportRequest {}
message ChanBackupSnapshot  {
    /**
    The set of new channels that have been added since the last channel backup
    snapshot was requested.
    */
    ChannelBackups single_chan_backups = 1 [ json_name = "single_chan_backups" ];

    /**
    A multi-channel backup that covers all open channels currently known to
    lnd.
    */
    //MultiChanBackup multi_chan_backup = 2 [ json_name = "multi_chan_backup" ];
}

message ChannelBackups {
    /**
    A set of single-chan static channel backups.
    */
    //repeated ChannelBackup chan_backups = 1 [ json_name = "chan_backups" ];
}
```

I dont get any build errors just a lnrpc.Rpc not found error during import

here is the example project
https://github.com/mandelmonkey/protoTest

Comment: Please post the error you get.

Comment: thanks I updated my comment with the error as well as the sample project in git showing the issue